# Group rows by column value and handle some rows differently while grouping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have this input data:

```
$tbldocumentacao_eleitoral_answers = array(
  array('id' => '1', 'sequence_answer_id' => '4', 'column_name' => 'form_id', 'column_value' => '3'),
  array('id' => '2', 'sequence_answer_id' => '4', 'column_name' => 'text-1625344899360', 'column_value' => '1000'),
  array('id' => '3', 'sequence_answer_id' => '4', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346513466', 'column_value' => 'Text 2'),
  array('id' => '4', 'sequence_answer_id' => '4', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346520950', 'column_value' => 'Text 3'),
  array('id' => '5', 'sequence_answer_id' => '4', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346541360', 'column_value' => 'VALUE ANY'),
  array('id' => '9', 'sequence_answer_id' => '5', 'column_name' => 'form_id', 'column_value' => '3'),
  array('id' => '10', 'sequence_answer_id' => '5', 'column_name' => 'text-1625344899360', 'column_value' => '1080'),
  array('id' => '11', 'sequence_answer_id' => '5', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346513466', 'column_value' => 'VALUE Any'),
  array('id' => '12', 'sequence_answer_id' => '5', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346520950', 'column_value' => 'taffarelxavier7@gmail.com'),
  array('id' => '13', 'sequence_answer_id' => '5', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346541360', 'column_value' => '63999480630'),
  array('id' => '17', 'sequence_answer_id' => '6', 'column_name' => 'form_id', 'column_value' => '3'),
  array('id' => '18', 'sequence_answer_id' => '6', 'column_name' => 'text-1625344899360', 'column_value' => '7895'),
  array('id' => '19', 'sequence_answer_id' => '6', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346513466', 'column_value' => 'IARA'),
  array('id' => '20', 'sequence_answer_id' => '6', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346520950', 'column_value' => 'taffa@gmail.com'),
  array('id' => '21', 'sequence_answer_id' => '6', 'column_name' => 'text-1625346541360', 'column_value' => '63999484570'),
);
```

I have been trying to solve this problem but with no success. My Code:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($tbldocumentacao_eleitoral_answers as $key => $value) {
  $result[$value['sequence_answer_id']][] = [$value['column_name']=>$value['column_name']];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Expected result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sequence_answer_id] => 4
            [text-1625344899360] => 1000
            [text-1625346513466] => Text 2
            [text-1625346520950] => Text 3
            [text-1625346541360] => VALUE ANY
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [sequence_answer_id] => 5
            [text-1625344899360] => 1080
            [text-1625346513466] => VALUE Any
            [text-1625346520950] => taffarelxavier7@gmail.com
            [text-1625346541360] => 63999480630
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [sequence_answer_id] => 6
            [text-1625344899360] => 7895
            [text-1625346513466] => IARA
            [text-1625346520950] => taffa@gmail.com
            [text-1625346541360] => 63999484570
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temporary keys then reindex the result when the loop is finished.

Conditionally, when iterating the row with the `form_id` value in the `column_name` element, declare the `sequence_answer_id` element in the grouped row.  Otherwise, store the `column_name` with the `column_value` in the grouped row.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/paX7q))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($tbldocumentacao_eleitoral_answers as $row) {
    if ($row['column_name'] === 'form_id') {
        $result[$row['sequence_answer_id']]['sequence_answer_id'] = $row['sequence_answer_id'];
    } else {
        $result[$row['sequence_answer_id']][$row['column_name']] = $row['column_value'];
    }
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this:

```
foreach ($tbldocumentacao_eleitoral_answers as $key => $value) {
  $result[$value['sequence_answer_id']][$value['column_name']] = $value['column_value'];
}
```

You most use `$value['column_name']` as key

In your code, you add array into new array

Comment: Please never post "Change your code to this" answers on Stack Overflow.  EVERY answer should include an educational explanation.  `$key` is a useless declaration.  I do not believe that your answer will generate the desired result.